# How can I build a wordpress gutenberg multiple blocks plugin that support dynamic content

Tags: wordpress, plugins, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I am creating a custom Wordpress theme with a set of custom Gutenberg Blocks. Previously I had all the blocks work as separate plugins and I started combining them into a single plugin as I thought it would be easier to maintain and update. My old folder structure looked like this:

```
wp-content
 |
 +-- plugins
 |  |
 |  +-- dir 1
 |  |  +-- build
 |  |  +-- node_modules
 |  |  +-- src
 |  |  |  +-- index.js (includes edit and save functions)
 |  |
 |  +-- dir 2
 |  |  +-- build
 |  |  +-- node_modules
 |  |  +-- src
 |  |  |  +-- index.js (includes edit and save functions)
```

My new folder stucture looks like this (learned from this project: https://github.com/rmorse/multiple-blocks-plugin)

```
wp-content
 |
 +-- plugins
 |  |
 |  +-- multiple-blocks-plugin
 |  |  |
 |  |  +-- blocks
 |  |  |  |
 |  |  |  +-- dir 1
 |  |  |  |  +-- build
 |  |  |  |  +-- src
 |  |  |  |  |  +-- edit.js
 |  |  |  |  |  +-- index.js
 |  |  |  |  |  +-- save.js
 |  |  |  |  +-- block.json
 |  |  |  |
 |  |  |  +-- dir 2
 |  |  |  |  +-- build
 |  |  |  |  +-- src
 |  |  |  |  |  +-- edit.js
 |  |  |  |  |  +-- index.js
 |  |  |  |  |  +-- save.js
 |  |  |  |  +-- block.json
 |  |  |  |
 |  |  |  +-- dir 3
 |  |  |  |  +-- build
 |  |  |  |  +-- src
 |  |  |  |  |  +-- edit.js
 |  |  |  |  |  +-- index.js
 |  |  |  |  +-- block.json
 |  |  |  |  +-- index.php (the callback function is stored here)
 |  |  | 
 |  |  +-- build
 |  |  +-- node_modules
 |  |  +-- multiple-blocks-plugin.php
```

Inside the `multiple-blocks-plugin.php` file, I maintain a list of all my plugins which I register using `register_block_type()` functions. These functions tell Wordpress to look for block.json files, where all my settings and attributes are now stored. One of my blocks is using dynamic content (a news block that should always show the latest three posts). My main problem is that I cannot get my new setup to read the `callback_function` when the function is stored inside the new folder structure. I aim to rebuild all my blocks to be dynamic, but I want to maintain a single plugin + multiple-block setup.

This is the function that registers all of the different blocks and the faulty one for `/blocks/news/`

```
function create_block_multiple_blocks_block_init()
{
  register_block_type(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'blocks/column-block/');
  register_block_type(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'blocks/column-block-prices/');
  register_block_type(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'blocks/column-block-services/');
  register_block_type(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'blocks/column-block-specialists/');
  register_block_type(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'blocks/counter/');
  register_block_type(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'blocks/counter-list/');
  register_block_type(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'blocks/cta-banner/');
  register_block_type(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'blocks/gallery/');
  register_block_type(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'blocks/gallery-image/');
  register_block_type(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'blocks/image-text-block/');
  register_block_type(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'blocks/hero/');
  register_block_type_from_metadata(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'blocks/news/', array(
    "callback_function" => "news_register_block"
  ));
  register_block_type(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'blocks/opening-hours/');
  register_block_type(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'blocks/opening-hours-list/');
  register_block_type(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'blocks/process/');
  register_block_type(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'blocks/process-list/');
  register_block_type(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'blocks/why-choose-us/');
  register_block_type(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'blocks/why-choose-us-list/');
}
add_action('init', 'create_block_multiple_blocks_block_init');
```

**Question**

How do I set up a project that uses dynamic blocks, where all blocks are stored inside a single plugin? I am quite new to Wordpress development - I am used to working in Sitecore - and I would love to learn how to best set up such a project. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use the DirectoryIterator to be as lazy as possible and scan that 'blocks' directory. Maybe I'd make it look if a block.json is present and then let it register this directory.

```
foreach ( $blocks = new DirectoryIterator( __DIR__ . '/blocks' ) as $item ) {
    if ( $item -> isDir() && !$item -> isDot() ) if ( file_exists( $item -> getPathname() . '/block.json' ) ) register_block_type( $item -> getPathname() ); 
}
```

Next step could be that you include a php file that is named exactly like the folder. In that folder you store a name-of-the-folder_render_callback function. If said file is present, include it and use the name-of-the-folder_render_callback in the register_block_type args.

```
foreach ( $blocks = new DirectoryIterator( __DIR__ . '/blocks' ) as $item ) {
    if ( $item -> isDir() && !$item -> isDot() ) if ( file_exists( $item -> getPathname() . '/block.json' ) ) {
        if ( file_exists( $item -> getPathname() . '/' . $item -> getBasename() . '.php' ) ) {
            include( $item -> getPathname() . '/' . $item -> getBasename() . '.php' );
            register_block_type( $item -> getPathname() , array( 'render_callback' => $item -> getBasename() . '_render_callback' ) );
        } else {
            register_block_type( $item -> getPathname() );
        }
    }
}
```

Untested, though.

Comment: Hi Sebastian. Thank you for your response. I like the loop you present, it makes the code much more compact. I tried including the PHP file like you suggest, but I still am not able to execute any function inside that particular file. Could you provide an example of the contents of name-of-the-folder.php file, including the callback function?

Comment: Hi again Sebastian. I went through your code line by line and found two mistakes. After fixing them, it finally works! A week of frustration is finally over. In your second if statement, you had two file_exists checks, and in your register_block_type you were using 'callback_function' instead of 'render_callback'. Nontheless, thanks for your quick guidance!

Comment: Hey Danny, yeah you're right. I corrected that.